# Perl ssh error handling when host not reachable

Tags: perl, networking, ssh, expect

I use expect in perl to do ssh, following is my code snipet.

```
my $exp = Expect->spawn("ssh renjithp\@192.168.1.12") or die "could not spawn ssh";
my $op = $exp->expect(undef,'renjithp>');
print "*$op*";
```

I wanted to handle the error if the host is not reachable (destination IP is down), I was in a impression die will hit when the ip is not reachable, but when i give a wrong IP script is not terminating and it continuous execution.

what is the right way to handle this scenario?

EDITED
I am observing $op value is 1 when the ssh is succesfull, and 0 when the destination IP is not up. is it right way to use $op to take a decision?

I have one more doubt, when the destination IP is not reachable why the control coming out of expect,i mean '$exp->expect(undef,'renjithp>');' should return only after its getting the prompt right?

Comment: Probably not the answer you want, but at one place I worked we gave up on the Expect module in the end in a similar scenario, and used command-line expect with scripts instead. Maybe it's improved since.

Comment: I think i got the reason why expect returns. **when the IP is not reachable, spawned process for ssh will terminate and this causes to close expect. To verify this i took a successful case and i put statement $exp->expect for something which is not expected, now the control is blocked at this point. When I killed SSH process from different terminal, the control from blocking expect came out. SO i feel I can use $op to verify ssh is success or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to make the ssh connection contingent on IP address reachability with the expect module, you should test connectivity with a `nc` first...

```
my $addr = "192.168.1.12";
if (system("nc -w 1 -z $addr 22")==0) {
    my $exp = Expect->spawn("ssh renjithp\@$addr") or die "could not spawn ssh";
    my $op = $exp->expect(undef,'renjithp>');
    print "*$op*";
} else {
    print "Host $addr is unreachable\n";
}
```

The `nc` command is [`netcat`](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)... `nc -z` tests for TCP port open

Alternatively, you could use a module like `Net::OpenSSH` that makes error handling a bit easier...

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host);
$ssh->error and
   die "Couldn't establish SSH connection: ". $ssh->error;
```

Comment: OK, thanks for the solution. What if the service is not running, IP is up but ssh service is not running, is there any way to check this along with ping ?

Comment: You can use `nc -z $addr 22` to test for the TCP port open... technically you can simply use the `nc` command to test both...

Answer (score 2):

use Net::OpenSSH:

```
use Net::OpenSSH;

my $ssh = Net::OpenSSH->new($host, timeout => 30);
if ($ssh->error) {
    die "Unable to connect to remote host: " . $ssh->error;
}
my $out = $ssh->capture($cmd);
...
```

Comment: That's good option, but I can not use OpenSSH since its not installed in target machine where it is intended use.

Comment: @Renjith: You only need it installed on the machine where the script is run, not on the target machine. In any case, installing Net::OpenSSH is quite easy, just copy the contents of the `lib` directory from the distribution in some place reachable from perl `@INC`.

Comment: 'target machine' I meant to say, where my script is finally used. There are many such machines, if I want to install some thing I have to follow proper procedure. Which is not something impossible,but some additional steps, let me see. Thanks